# How to play streaming on ionic1?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, video-streaming, html5-video

How to play streaming on ionic1?

Do you recommend angularjs video http://www.videogular.com/? Or some plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about https://github.com/nchutchind/cordova-plugin-streaming-media

Depends upon the source too though. A simple video tag will also suffice if you're using a common format.

Comment: Can you help me ? @devesh-sati

Comment: What do you need ?

Comment: I had put my code, but the people that comments asked to edit the question and a person in the stack deleted my doubt that it was with my code. I'm going to create a new question and can I call you on the other question? Is about the same subject almost.

Comment: Yes sure. Go ahead please

Comment: My question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944208/how-can-i-get-a-streaming-link-in-ionics-videoplayer) @devesh-sati